# Tags know as string in template

Tags: python, django

I use nicedit for admin site. It save data with tags, as shown here:
[image: admin page]

I expect it render HTML tags in page but it display string instead, as image below:
[image: tag show is string]

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I guess tags should be [marked save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: Try to avoid links to images, add as text formatted as code instead.

Comment: @Charnel meant to say "marked safe". Django will normally not mark variables as safe when rendering them in a template because this can lead to big security issues if you don't know what HTML is added.

Comment: yes, sorry, `safe` not `save`

Comment: Thanks for help. My issue was resolved with safe filter.